# Does Webpack's ( target: ['web', 'es5'] ) Replace Babel for IE11 support?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, internet-explorer-11, core-js

IE11 supports es5, So can `target: ['web', 'es5']` in `webpack.config.js` replace Babel polyfills, core-js, @preset-env. and all these complex configurations ?

Comment: In my opinion, this will work if all resources in your project are encoded in ES5 syntax. Maybe you could refer to [this doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it only transforms Webpack runtime code.